# Cannot get the type of List<SObject>

Tags: apex, controller, integration, debugging

I am trying to find the type of a list using Schema class.

Below is my code

**Main Method**

```
   public void upsertCase(SlackWrappers.SessionCreateResponse rsp, String 
     sObjectId) {
    system.debug('Inside upsertCase');

    sfcase.CustomerLink__c = rsp.end_customer_link;
    sfcase.SupportLink__c = rsp.supporter_link;
    sfcase.CaseId__c = rsp.code;
    sfcase.parentId__c = sObjectId;
    try {
        Datetime expirationLink = (datetime)json.deserialize('"' + rsp.valid_until + '"', datetime.class);
        sfcase.ExpirationDate__c = expirationLink;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.debug(e);
    }
    system.debug('ServiceCase to be upserted---->'+sfcase);
    performDMLOperationWithExternalId(salesforceCase);
}
```

**Helper Classes**

```
 public static void upsertAsUserWithExternalId(sObject obj)
  {performDMLOperationWithExternalId(new List<sObject>
 {obj},Operation.OP_UPSERT);}

     private static void performDMLOperationWithExternalId(List<SObject> 
 objList, Operation dmlOperation){
    system.debug('Inside performDMLOperationWithExternalId');
    system.debug('objList to be upserted--->'+objList);
    System.debug('objectName--->'+objList.getSObjectType());
    Map<SObjectType,List<Id>> objTypeMap = analyzeDMLCollection(objList, 
     dmlOperation);

    checkCRUDPermission(objTypeMap.keySet(),dmlOperation);

    if (dmlOperation == Operation.OP_UPSERT && objectName != null){
        if(objectName == 'SlackTeam_Case__c'){
        List<SlackTeam_Case__c> serviceCaseToUpsert = 
        (List<SlackTeam_Case__c>)(objList);
        upsert serviceCaseToUpsert parentId__c;
        } 
    } 
}
```

On debugging, I have found that the statement

```
System.debug('objectName--->'+objList.getSObjectType());
```

is returning **null** though objList is ---> (SlackTeam_Case__c:{CustomerLink__c =https://get.slackteam.com/v17/c43199517, SupportLink__c =https://get.slackteam.com/v17/c43199517-Rasjdhkaj45, CaseId__c =c43-199-517, ParentId__c=5000Y00000FhNfCQAV, ExpirationDate__c =2017-07-26 17:20:22})

In order to upsert the list properly, I need to get objectName as SlackTeam_Case__c. How can I get the actual `SObjectType`?

Comment: That shouldn't even compile. The `List.getSObjectType()` method returns a `Schema.SObjectType` instance, not a `String`.

Comment: Sorry, I have updated my code. I was not storing it into a string. Was trying to print it directly.

Answer (score 4):

Two things are wrong here:

```
public static void upsertAsUserWithExternalId(sObject obj)
  {performDMLOperationWithExternalId(new List<sObject>
 {obj},Operation.OP_UPSERT);}
```

Since you used a `List<sObject>`, it has no type. Instead, you'll want to come up with the correct list type, something like this:

```
public static void upsertAsUserWithExternalId(sObject obj) {
    SObject[] objList = (SObject[]) Type.forName('List<'+obj.getSObjectType()+'>').newInstance();
    objList.add(obj);
    performDMLOperationWithExternalId(objList, Operation.OP_UPSERT);
}
```

Also, you should include a field token so you know what field to upsert by:

```
public static void upsertAsUserWithExternalId(sObject obj, sobjectField extIdField) {
    SObject[] objList = (SObject[]) Type.forName('List<'+obj.getSObjectType()+'>').newInstance();
    objList.add(obj);
    performDMLOperationWithExternalId(objList, Operation.OP_UPSERT, extIdField);
}
```

Then, you can do the following:

```
if (dmlOperation == Operation.OP_UPSERT) {
    Database.upsert(objList, extIdField);
}
```

Comment: I'm once again dumbstruck by your cleverness - It never occurred to me that you could do `Type.forName('List<'+obj.getSObjectType()+'>').newInstance()` - I've always used `Type.forName(xx).newInstance()` in past to construct Apex classes/inner classes and never thought about dynamic lists of concrete sobject types.  This worked me out of a jam wherein I was getting null on `someList.getSobjectType()` when all list members were some concrete sobjectType. Thanks!

Comment: @cropredy There's a lot of really nifty gems hidden in my some odd 5k answers. I'm going to try and compile them all into a legible form for people that are interested.

Answer (score 0):

When I wrote a [`DML`](https://github.com/apexlarson/DML) utility, I just added the `SObjectType` as a parameter, since I didn't always get reliable results calling `getSObjectType`. I recommend you do the same.

```
public static void doSomeDml(List<SObject> records, SObjectType listType /*, other parameters*/)
{
    // implementation
}
```